# Index textboxes value (from two textboxes)

Tags: vb.net

I have the two textboxes:

First:

```
Textbox1.lines(0) = 50
Textbox1.lines(1) = 65
Textbox1.lines(2) = 41
Textbox1.lines(3) = 27
Textbox1.lines(4) = 6
Textbox1.lines(5) = 6
```

Second:

```
Textbox2.lines(0) = 27
Textbox2.lines(1) = 41
Textbox2.lines(2) = 65
Textbox2.lines(3) = 6
Textbox2.lines(4) = 50
Textbox2.lines(5) = 6
```

in a third textbox I should display the index that contains the values ​​from the first textbox, but in the second.

```
Textbox3.lines(0) = 4 (50 of the first textbox is on the second line (lines4)
Textbox3.lines(1) = 2 (65 of the first textbox is on the second line (lines2)
Textbox3.lines(2) = 1 (41 of the first textbox is on the second line (lines1)
Textbox3.lines(3) = 0 (27 of the first textbox is on the second line (lines0)
Textbox3.lines(4) = 3 (6 of the first textbox is on the second line (lines4)
Textbox3.lines(5) = 5 (6 of the first textbox is on the second line (lines5)
```

although it already exists on line 4 (Number 6), we will move next line, because that line has already been considered. or both index can be displayed.
or somehow the line value becomes null (0) so that it is not taken.

Code: it doesn't work properly, unfortunately.

```
   For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
            For l As Integer = 1 To TextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
                If TextBox2.Lines(l) = line Then
                    TextBox3.AppendText(l)
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
 For Each line In TextBox1.Lines

     Dim i As Integer = 0
     While (i < TextBox1.Lines.Length)

         If TextBox2.Lines(i) = line Then
             TextBox3.AppendText(i & Environment.NewLine)
             Continue For
         End If

         i += 1
     End While

 Next
```

With **Continue For**, the code go to the for's next loop.

Or if you want to display all iterations :

```
 For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
    
     Dim i As Integer = 0
     While (i < TextBox1.Lines.Length)
    
         If TextBox2.Lines(i) = line Then
             TextBox3.AppendText(i & " ")
         End If
    
         i += 1
     End While

     TextBox3.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
  Next
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output.  For the second six, it is outputting 3 instead of 5 as described in the problem description.

Comment: He say "we will move next line, because that line has already been considered. or both index can be displayed". I chose to go to the next line.

I edit my answer to add the 2nd option

Comment: Right, I think by "we will move next line", he meant to find the next line in TextBox2 where that number occurs, thus the 5 instead of 3.  It is not worded very well.  I suppose we'll just have to see what the author really meant.  =)

Comment: Yes ^^ I hope it will help

Comment: Each line must have a single one. if the line already existed in the past, we will go next. I managed to make it work, and I also posted an answer the way I did it. Thanks for the answers, I will analyze them to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses a Dictionary with the number as the key, and a Queue of indices as the value.

When we first encounter a number from TextBox1, we build a queue of all indices where the number occurs in TextBox2.  Then each time we encounter that number, we dequeue the next available number where it occurred.  If there are none left, then we return -1.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim results As New List(Of String)
    Dim occurrences As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Queue(Of Integer))
    For Each number As String In TextBox1.Lines
        If Not occurrences.ContainsKey(number) Then
            occurrences.Add(number, New Queue(Of Integer))
            For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox2.Lines.Count - 1
                If TextBox2.Lines(i) = number Then
                    occurrences(number).Enqueue(i)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If occurrences(number).Count > 0 Then
            results.Add(occurrences(number).Dequeue)
        Else
            results.Add("-1")
        End If
    Next
    TextBox3.Lines = results.ToArray
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that as well with the help of a list. In order to work, the number of lines must be equal.

```
  Dim valI As New List(Of Integer)
        For nIndex As Integer = 0 To Textbox2.Lines.Length -1
            For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
                If TextBox2.Lines(nIndex) = TextBox1.Lines(i) Then
                    If valI.Contains(i) Then
                    Else
                        valI.Add(i)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            Textbox3.AppendText(vbNewline & valI.Item(nIndex))
        Next
```